# arguments not passed run java command line

Tags: java, bash, sh

i wrote script bash file that by it i can run java file and pass argument to this class but the java file doesn't recognize this argument.
this the sh file:

```
for Agentid in `seq 1 3`;
do
gnome-terminal -x sh -c "java -cp target/classes:../../lib/cafe.jar:target/ddspaxos.jar \
paxosdds.PaxosAgent $Agentid ; bash" 
done
```

this the main function of this class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        // création de l'agent Paxos
        PaxosAgent P = new PaxosAgent();
        System.out.println("<<<<<<<<Agent created>>>>>>>>");
        System.out.println(args[0]);
        if (args.length == 1) {
            // Lecture à partir d'un fichier de configuration
            AgentId = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            if (AgentId == 1) {
                isLeader = true;
                System.out.println("<<<<<<<<i leader>>>>>>>>");
                // récuprération des propositions du  fichier scénario.txt 
                InputStream ips = new FileInputStream("scenario.txt");
                InputStreamReader ipsr = new InputStreamReader(ips);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ipsr);
                String ligne;
                while ((ligne = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    parseAndExecuteLine(ligne);
                }
                br.close();

            } else {
                isLeader = false;
            }

        }

    }
```

the script run three terminals but show only this message `<<<agent created>>>>`
and doesn't receive the argument value.

Comment: Try changing it to `if ( args.length >= 1 )` instead of  `== 1`.

Comment: i did but nothing change it doesn't receive the argument passed by the bash script

Comment: Can you try `gnome-terminal -x sh -c "echo java -cp target/classes:../../lib/cafe.jar:target/ddspaxos.jar \
paxosdds.PaxosAgent $Agentid  >> /tmp/walid.tmp"

Comment: i tried nothing showed now

Comment: i changed the script code like that :  for Agentid in `seq 1 3`;
do
gnome-terminal -x sh -c 'java -cp target/classes:../../lib/cafe.jar:target/ddspaxos.jar  \
paxosdds.PaxosAgent "$Agentid" ; bash'
done but i get this exception xception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)

Answer (score 0):

The script you posted in the your last comment fails because single quotes doesn´t expand variables and java is receiving the String $AgentId, not the numeric value.

I cant´t test your example (no gnome-terminal installed) but I try with a similar one.

Test class:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        if (args.length == 1) {
            final int AgentId = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            if (AgentId == 1) {
                System.out.println("1!");
            }else{
                System.out.println("not 1!");
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("param not found");
        }
    }
}
```

Shell command line (it works):

```
for id in `seq 1 3`; do
    sh -c "sh -c \" java -cp . Test ${id} ; sh \" "
done
```

So I think you need something like this (I can´t test it):

```
for id in `seq 1 3`; do
    gnome-terminal -x sh -c " java -cp . Test ${id} ; sh " 
done
```